# Vue.js infinite loop with prop array

Tags: vue.js

In my App.vue:

- I'm using `updated()` for getting user info after callback and each time I change the route and getting info and
- `mounted()`, if I used F5 or go to my website already connected with SSO

The problem is that in my `updated()`, I set an array which is passed to a component. It make infinity loop.
**How can I avoid it ?**

`App.vue` :

```js
<template>
        <Sidebar v-if="isLoggedIn" :displayName="currentUser" v-bind:role="rolesT" />
</template>
<script lang="ts">
  public rolesT: ReadonlyArray<String> = ["test"];
  public initUser() {
    this.auth = Vue.prototype.$auth;
    this.auth.getUser().then((user) => {
      if (user !== null) {
        this.currentUser = user.profile.name!;
        this.accessTokenExpired = user.expired;
        this.rolesT = []; // if I use only this one, I have infinite loop 
        this.rolesT = user.profile.roles ; // if I use only this one, I have infinite loop
        this.rolesT = this.rolesT; // if I use only this one, I dont have infinite loop, but its useless, it was just for test
        console.log(this.rolesT);
      }
      this.isLoggedIn = (user !== null && !user.expired);
    });
  }
  public mounted() {
    console.log("mounted");
    this.initUser();
  }

  public updated() {
    console.log("updated");
    this.initUser();
  }
}
</script>
```

`Sidebar.vue` (I do nothing with the array for now, but still loop) :

```js
[...]
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';
@Component
export default class Sidebar extends Vue {
  @Prop({default: 'Unknow name'})
  private displayName!: string;
  @Prop({default: 'Unknow username'})
  private username!: string;
  @Prop()
  private role;
}
</script>
```

Comment: There should be a tag [tag:vue.ts]. And btw, I hate TS.

Comment: why dont watch over route or info? cant put a boolean property like `NeedUpdate`  and check it in update and initUser  change it to false

Comment: @connexo, I can you js too, but I think the problem will be the same

Comment: @Mohsen, what do you mean by watch route or info ? Yes I can put a boolean to do it only once, but it's a pretty bad patch. I prefer to understand why and fix my issue